# How to export one line per file using shell script or sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have

```
#file.txt
VAR1=foo
VAR2=bar
VAR3=moo
```

I need three files: VAR1, VAR2 and VAR3 and contains

```
#VAR1
foo

#VAR2
bar

#VAR3
moo
```

Comment: See [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  filename=${line%=*}
  content=${line#*=}
  echo "${content}" > "${filename}"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Don't. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Noted, solves this specific use case correctly. Can probably write up something in a different language though.

Comment: Not necessarily. It all depends what `foo`, etc. REALLY are. If they contain a backslash, or quoted space or equals signs or... then that script will fail (hint: **always** use `while IFS= read -r line` unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so and fully understand all the implications). It will also be an order of magnitude slower than, say, an awk script but that only really matters if/when the file is large.